# How do I synchronize between Jetpack Compose navigation backstack and the selected state of the icon of Navigation bar

Tags: android, navigation, back-stack, jetpack

First, the code:

```
data class Destination (
    val title: String,
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val route: String
)

@Composable
fun ExperimentWithBackButtonPress(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val listOfDestinations = listOf (
        Destination ("Home Screen", Icons.Default.Home, "home_screen"),
        Destination ("Settings Screen", Icons.Default.Settings, "settings_screen"),
    )

    var currentSelection by remember { mutableStateOf(listOfDestinations[0])}

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier,
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {
                listOfDestinations.forEach { destination ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        selected = currentSelection == destination,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(destination.route) {
                                popUpTo(listOfDestinations[0].route) {
                                    inclusive = false
                                }
                            }
                            currentSelection = destination
                        },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = destination.icon,
                                contentDescription = destination.title
                            )
                        },
                        label = {
                            Text(text = destination.title)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = listOfDestinations[0].route
            ) {
                composable(listOfDestinations[0].route) {
                    ScreenTemplate(
                        label = listOfDestinations[0].title,
                        modifier = modifier
                    )
                }

                composable(listOfDestinations[1].route) {
                    ScreenTemplate(
                        label = listOfDestinations[1].title,
                        modifier = modifier
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun ScreenTemplate(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: String,
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = modifier,
            text = label,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium
        )
    }
}
```

**What is the issue?**

After navigating from one screen to another - and after that when I press back button - the screen navigates to NavigationDestinations.Reference as expected. BUT, the icon in the NavigationBar is still highlighted for the Navigation.Interpolation screen - meaning it doen't change with back button press.

**How do I address that?**

I don't understand how to handle Backpress event and sync that with the selection procedure.

[image]